# Why did my phone start ringing when there is no SIM card installed

Tags: calls

My old samsung jet phone just started ringing from inside the cupboard, & unknown caller was displayed, although the children use it as a play phone sometimes there is no SIM card installed, how can that happen I thought you had to have a sim in to operate a phone except for emergency calls?

Comment: It looks like a fake calling app is doing this. Check the list of installed apps.

Comment: Did you pick it up? Was there someone on the other end? I rather guess Sachin is right, but just to make sure ;)

Answer (score 1):

That happened to my Samsung Wi-Fi "not smartphone, just touch".

I live in jordan, and I received a call twice from an unknown number. It rang with no sound on the microphone and no SIM card. It is really weird, but I think the most common factor is the Samsung phone. It might be kind of an emergency call, or the company puts kind of tracking system to see if these devices are still in service.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a call from Google+. See if the Google+ app is installed. If it is, then disable/uninstall it.